# I need to port simplest web page from .jsp to .asp, but I get http error 500.100

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, web

I have a jsp page that reads one line from a certain url and sends to the client:

```
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>
<%
    URL myUrl = new URL("http://host.com");
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(
                     myUrl.openStream()));

   out.println(in.readLine());
%>
```

I would like to have same functionality for IIS:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#">
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<%
WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.host.com"); 
WebResponse myWebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse(); 
Stream ReceiveStream = myWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream);
Response.Write(reader.ReadLine());
%>
```

But I get an error code:
    Error Type:
    Active Server Pages, ASP 0221 (0x80004005)
    The specified 'Page Language="C#"> <%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" ' option is unknown or          invalid.
    index.asp, line 1

What I do wrong?

Comment: Did you already register ASP.net in IIS?

Comment: You need to rename your file to `index.aspx' - note the 'x' at the end.

Comment: I've renamed the file, now it is index.aspx:
This error can be caused if there is no default page available and directory browsing has not been enabled for the directory, or if you are trying to display an HTML page that resides in a directory marked for Execute or Script permissions only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to process it using legacy ASP, not ASP.NET.

Comment: Steve, this is because ASP.NET isn't installed properly or not registered in IIS. There is a plenty of articles explaining that. http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Set-Up-IIS-ASP.NET.aspx